# DateTime not yielding same time when using epoch time but initialized with different timezones

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timezone

I saved a value in MySQL using the `bigint` column type for a date of August 11, 2013 - 11:55 PM (EST TIME)

This is saved as unix time in the `bigint` column with value : `1376279700`

I understand this to be epoch time since `1970 jan 01,01 00:00:00` in seconds.  So I presumed that if I initialize DateTime using any timezone it should yield `08/11/2013 - 11:55 PM` ( and whatever timezone used when initialized).

but given following code:

```
$time1 = new DateTime("@1376279700");
$time1->setTimezone("Europe/London");
echo "Created Europe/London - ".$time1->format(DateTime::RFC822);
```

and

```
$time2 = new DateTime("@1376279700");
$time2->setTimezone("America/New_York");
echo "Created America/New_York - ".$time2->format(DateTime::RFC822);
```

I get these values:

> Created: Europe/London - Mon, 12 Aug 13 04:55:00 +0100

and

> Created: America/New_York - Sun, 11 Aug 13 23:55:00 -0400

The `Europe/London` timezone self-adjusts and somehow magically it knows that `1376279700` was created using EST timezone.

I am very confused here. Please shed some light here.  I am trying to create a timezone aware function where start date of an event (`08/11/2013 11:55 PM`) is used by my user's timezone.

Comment: "The $timezone parameter and the current timezone are ignored when the $time parameter either is a UNIX timestamp (e.g. @946684800) or specifies a timezone (e.g. 2010-01-28T15:00:00+02:00)." [Source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php)

Comment: Why aren't you using the correct data type in mysql?  You should use `DateTime`, not `bigint`.  Also, any time you are referring to the time since the epoch - that is in UTC.

Comment: I can't use mysql date type for DB portability. Thank you, I got my answer. Two thing I learned.. Unix time on DateTime constructor ignores timezone.  And epoch time is always UTC.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor ignores the timezone when you pass a Unix timestamp.

```
$ts = new DateTime('@946684800');
echo $ts->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . PHP_EOL;          // 2000-01-01 00:00:00

// Setting the time zone does nothing *here* . . .
$pac_tz = new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
$ts = new DateTime('@946684800', $pac_tz);
echo $ts->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . PHP_EOL;          // 2000-01-01 00:00:00

// But you can ask for the "same" timestamp 
// in a particular time zone.
$ts->setTimeZone($pac_tz);
echo $ts->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . PHP_EOL;          // 1999-12-31 16:00:00

echo '=============' .PHP_EOL;

$time1 = new DateTime("@1376279700");
echo $time1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').PHP_EOL;         // 2013-08-12 03:55:00

$time1_tz = new DateTimeZone("Europe/London");
$time1->setTimezone($time1_tz);
// If it's 2013-08-12 03:55:00 in UTC, what time is it in London?
// London isn't on UTC in the summer (now, as I write this). 
echo "Created Europe/London - ".$time1->format(DateTime::RFC822) . PHP_EOL;

$time2 = new DateTime("@1376279700");               // Same as $time1
echo $time2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').PHP_EOL;

$time2_tz = new DateTimeZone("America/New_York");
// If it's 2013-08-12 03:55:00 in UTC, what time is it in New York?
$time2->setTimezone($time2_tz);
echo "Created America/New_York - ".$time2->format(DateTime::RFC822) . PHP_EOL;
```

All the output . . .

```
2000-01-01 00:00:00
2000-01-01 00:00:00
1999-12-31 16:00:00
=============
2013-08-12 03:55:00
Created Europe/London - Mon, 12 Aug 13 04:55:00 +0100
2013-08-12 03:55:00
Created America/New_York - Sun, 11 Aug 13 23:55:00 -0400
```